# Unable to Add User after Site Migration

Tags: wp-admin, user-registration

After migrating a WordPress 4.7.2 site from staging to production, everything seems to be working fine except that I cannot add a new user. The All Users screen shows my existing 2 admin accounts that came from my staging site, plus a blank line with no name/edit button etc, which looks like a ghost entry. When I click on "Add New" I can enter and submit a new user, but it never shows in the list of users. Any tips to what happened and what I need to do to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Are there any errors showing up in the browser javascript console?

  - Are you sure the migration process was properly handled? The files and the database were completely backed up and migrated?
  - This migration process was made manually or by using a plugin?
  - Have you tried to disable each of the plugins, one by one, while testing if after each of the plugins are deactivated, to see if the function of adding users works again?

Will be waiting for an answer. Let's see if we can find a solution for it.

Comment: Thank you for your post, questions as answers are off-topic, if you need more info make a comment please.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan

Regarding what you wrote, do you still have a full backup of the site you migrated (files and database)?

Also, have you tried migrating it to another server (online or local) ?

PS: Sorry for not replying directly to what you wrote but I can't reply yet because I just started on stackexchange and I still need to increase my reputation score.